# Tcl: How to replace variable string?

Tags: tcl

Input file is a tcl script and it looks like:

```
set PATH /user/abc/path
set PATH2 /user/abc/path2
...
read_verilog ${PATH}/src/vlog/code_1.v
read_verilog $PATH/src/vlog/code_2.v
read_vhdl ${PATH2}/src/vhd/code_3.vh
read_vhdl $PATH2/src/vhd/code_4.vh
[other commands ...]
```

---

Need to check if the source file is exist and print out none-exist files.
If none of the file is exist, the output looks like:

```
read_verilog ${PATH}/src/vlog/code_1.v
read_verilog $PATH/src/vlog/code_2.v
read_vhdl ${PATH2}/src/vhd/code_3.vh
read_vhdl $PATH2/src/vhd/code_4.vh
```

And below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set input_file    "input.tcl"

set input_fpt        [open $input_file r]
set input_lines_all  [read $input_fpt]
set input_lines      [split $input_lines_all "\n"]

set PATH /user/abc/PATH
set PATH /user/dgc/PATH2

foreach line $input_lines {
   if { [string match "read_verilog *" $line] || [string match "read_vhdl*" $line] } {
      regexp {[read_verilog read_vhdl] (.*)} $line matched file

      if { [string match {*[{P]AT[H}]*} $file] } {
         set abs_file [string map {${PATH} /user/abc/PATH} $file]
      } elseif { [string match "*PATH2*" $file] } {
         set abs_file [string map {${PATH2} /user/abc/PATH2} $file]
      } else {
         set abs_file $file
      }

      if { ![file exists $abs_file] } {
         puts $line
      }
   }
}
```

My script can't check $PATH and not sure if there is a more efficient way to do the job.

Comment: check puts command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing just the substitutions you want is with the `string map` command. Build up the map piece by piece first, then apply it to your string.

```
set map {} 
lappend map {$PATH} $PATH
lappend map {${PATH}} $PATH
lappend map {$PATH2} $PATH2
lappend map {${PATH2}} $PATH2

set modified [string map $map $inputString]
```

You can apply the map as many times as you want once you have built it, and transform your data either a line at a time or all in one go. *However*, you might be better off just evaluating the file as a Tcl script. That can be an incredibly useful approach to some types of parsing (especially when used in conjunction with a safe interpreter) if the input is suitable, which yours appears to be.